# Convert Excel 95 to Excel97+ without automation?

Tags: .net, excel

I have an Excel 95 workbook, and I need to convert it into a format that is at least Excel 97, although preferably Excel 2003. I don't want to use office automation as this has all kinds of issues. Is there any way to do this in a .Net managed way?

Answer (score 2):

I have found an application called Gnumeric for Linux and it has an excellent converter program called ssconvert included with it. Best of all, it has a port to Windows so you can use the ssconvert.exe to run this command:

ssconvert c:\OldExcelFile.xls c:\NewExcelFile.xlsx

It automatically figures you want to convert to the new version of Excel from the command line. Much better than the app I was going to pay £1000+ for a server licence!! GNU Free software rocks!!

Download it from: projects.gnome.org/gnumeric/downloads.shtml

Answer (score 0):

If this is a single workbook, why not just open it with Excel 2003 and save it?

Comment: This is not a single workbook as I see that I implied with the question. This will be a server-side process that does the file conversion, and it could happen on any number of workbooks.

Comment: OK if you are looking for some .net code that reads xl95 format and spits out xl2003 format then I don't know know to help you.
But its hard to tell the difference between an xl95 file and an xl95 file upgraded to xl2003 (there is more of a potential problem when downgrading).